# How to block a particular pop-up window from opening?

Tags: firefox, blocking, popups, adblock

Using Firefox (v.27.0.1) to browse a [news site](http://calcalist.co.il), I have a problem of recurring ad pop-up windows, originating from a specific website (amazing-offers.co.il). The ad pops-up when the news page is loaded, and then every couple of minutes when it automatically refreshes itself. It is **very** annoying.

I would like to block this pop-up from opening. Trying the Adblock Plus preferences, adding a filter `||amazing-offers.co.il` in a new custom group, prevents the contents of the ad from displaying, but not its window from popping up.

It appears that he Firefox's "Block pop-up windows" UI setting does not prevent this pop-up.

Is there a way to prevent this window, from this ad server, from repeatedly opening without eliminating all other pop-ups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From too many years ago I have **any** popup in my Firefox, I decide what to block and what not, how i did this?, just still using `Adblock plus` but in combination with `NoScript`, this way you disable all the annoyings Scripts and popups.

[NoScript - JavaScript/Java/Flash blocker for a safer Firefox ...](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/noscript/)

Comment: Thanks, more aggressive than the other solution, but seem to be doing the job. Requires tweaking on-the-fly to unblock leggit page components.

Answer (score 2):

Get [additional add-on to your adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus-pop-up-addon/).

"Adblock Plus Pop-up Addon extends the blocking functionality of Adblock Plus to those annoying pop-up windows that open on mouse clicks and other user actions."

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work after some tweaking. let's see if it stands the test of time, and if it does not "overdo" its job.

Comment: Did it stand the test of time? If yes, please select accepted answer from the two available.

Comment: I am currently using the NoScript. It has its annoyances, but I am slowly learning to live with it. Then, I'll get back to the add-on one. This will take time, and if I come to a definitive conclusion that one of them remains on my browser, I'll select the answer. Be patient. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you insist on that. I am not accepting an answer until I think it actually answered *my* question. As I wrote, I am still evaluating the suggested solutions.  did upvote the two answers to show that they both work (for now, at least).

Comment: Chill. Apparently you don't get it. You are using @ElektroStudios solution already. It doesn't matter how long you want to test stuff or how many questions will arise from now on in the future. The fact is his suggestion is correct => accept answer. It's a reward for his research/knowledge/time/attention spent on your problem. 
P.S. I never understood people like you. You get free and fast help, yet you are unwilling to show appreciation towards the person who solved your issue.

Comment: Out of respect to you answering my question, I will not reply to your last comment. If my intentions were not clear with what said so far, then probably nothing more I'll say won't change it. Thanks again for your help.